# How I can use Font Awesome as a stroke

Tags: css, text, font-awesome, stroke

I need to use FontAwesome as stroke I use

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #cc0000;
-webkit-text-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
```

but it works with webkit browsers only.

Any other way to make it works with other browsers like Firefox and IE +10

Thinks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this article: [Adding Stroke to Web text](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) they speak about using `text-shadow` to simulate the `-webkit-text-stroke` option; other than that there are no other options I am aware of.

```
h1 {
   -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
   color: white;
   text-shadow:
       3px 3px 0 #000,
     -1px -1px 0 #000,  
      1px -1px 0 #000,
      -1px 1px 0 #000,
       1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

From [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke)

Comment: Thinks for your help :)

Comment: This works well with 1px strokes, but anything beyond that begins to break down. I just discovered a wonderful tool here that does all of the crazy math for you to figure out where to apply text-shadows to truly simulate text-stroke: http://owumaro.github.io/text-stroke-generator/